# Can a single Spring's KafkaConsumer listener listens to multiple topic?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Anyone know if a single listener can listens to multiple topic like below? I know just "topic1" works, what if I want to add additional topics? Can you please show example for both below? Thanks for the help!

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic1,topic2")
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Acknowledgment ack) {
    System.out.println(record);
}
```

or

```
ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties(new TopicPartitionInitialOffset("topic1, topic2", 0));
```

Comment: My case need to connect one Kafka topic to fetch data using spring boot   this data having another Kafka topic name read this information and connect to new topic fetch the data and perform some business logic  . could you please help me to write spring boot code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, just follow the `@KafkaListener` JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * The topics for this listener.
 * The entries can be 'topic name', 'property-placeholder keys' or 'expressions'.
 * Expression must be resolved to the topic name.
 * Mutually exclusive with {@link #topicPattern()} and {@link #topicPartitions()}.
 * @return the topic names or expressions (SpEL) to listen to.
 */
String[] topics() default {};

/**
 * The topic pattern for this listener.
 * The entries can be 'topic name', 'property-placeholder keys' or 'expressions'.
 * Expression must be resolved to the topic pattern.
 * Mutually exclusive with {@link #topics()} and {@link #topicPartitions()}.
 * @return the topic pattern or expression (SpEL).
 */
String topicPattern() default "";

/**
 * The topicPartitions for this listener.
 * Mutually exclusive with {@link #topicPattern()} and {@link #topics()}.
 * @return the topic names or expressions (SpEL) to listen to.
 */
TopicPartition[] topicPartitions() default {};
```

So, your use-case should be like:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"topic1" , "topic2"})
```

Comment: And for the other case, you need a `TopicPartitionInitialOffset` for each one.

Comment: thank you both, VERY HELPFUL! also got Gary's way working!

Comment: Is there a way to configure different containerFactories for different topics with the same listener? In my case, the message format will be different for different topics.

Comment: No, you need to have different `@KafkaListener`, for its own `containerFactory`

Comment: May i know how this works for batch listener, suppose if we have batch listener with `2` topics and concurrency `1`, by any chance single batch poll can get data from both the topic ?  @ArtemBilan and @GaryRussell

Comment: That's correct. See JavaDocs of `KafkaConsumer.poll()`: ` Fetch data for the topics or partitions specified using one of the subscribe/assign APIs.`

Comment: 2.3.2 added a new property `subBatchPerPartition`, when true, the container will hand the listener a batch of records for each partition. It breaks up the records returned by the poll.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, but any information will help me if you can point me to separate batches based on topics instead of partition @GaryRussell and ArtemBilan

Comment: There is no support for that; we can't control what Kafka sends us. `ConsumerRecords` has no API to get just the records for a single topic - only to get the records for a single partition. In future, don't ask new questions in comments on old answers.

Comment: Well, that way it would be better to have separate `@KafkaListener` for each topic.

Comment: @GaryRussell Is it a good practice to listen to multiple topics on single listener. Lets say 5 topics. Each topic receiving data at a rate of 100 messages per sec(Just an example).

Comment: I don't answer new questions in comments on old answers; especially when they are nearly 3 years old. You should ask a new question. That said, your question is difficult to answer; it depends on many things.

Comment: @ArtemBilan is there a way I can specify multiple topics using properties value like `topics= "${mutlipleTopics}"` and define multipleTopics in application.properties file? I tried doing that but getting InvalidTopicException

Answer (score 5):

If we have to fetch multiple topics from the application.properties file :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = { "${spring.kafka.topic1}", "${spring.kafka.topic2}" })
```