# How to publish the messages to two topics from single producer and consuming in single listener in Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am Trying to publish messages two different topics from single producer.

**here i created two topics:**

```
   @Bean
    public NewTopic multi1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("multi1").partitions(1).build();
    }
    @Bean
    public NewTopic multi2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("multi2").partitions(1).build();
    }
```

this is how iam sending the messages to two topics:

```
public void sendingtomultitopic()
{
    IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i->this.template.send("multi1", "mutli1 data value->"+i));      
    IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i->this.template.send("multi2", "multi2 data value->"+i));
    logger.info("sending finished");
}
```

**is above method is correct way to send to multiple topics?**

here below iam trying to consume messages

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"multi1,multi2"}, groupId = "diffgroupid3")
    public void consumingfrommultitopics(String data) {
        logger.info(String.format("consumingfromtwotopics -> %s", data));
    }
```

exception iam receiving:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: [multi1,multi2]
```

iam able to the published data in those two topics.

**but this consumer is not retrieving any messages, please help me here?**

Comment: try defining the multiple topic names like ``topics = {"multi1","multi2"}``

Comment: yes i missed that typo error

Comment: is that the correct way to publish the messages to multiple topics

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Yes; it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use from config (application.yml)

```
test:
  kafka:
    sender:
      serverAddress: xxxxx:port
    topic:
      consumer: topic1,topic2
```

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${test.kafka.topic}'.split(',')}"
  public void consumingfrommultitopics(String data) {
        logger.info(String.format("consumingfromtwotopics -> %s", data));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in 'topics' form, should be

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"multi1","multi2"}...
```

(check out [Can a single Spring's KafkaConsumer listener listens to multiple topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861207/can-a-single-springs-kafkaconsumer-listener-listens-to-multiple-topic))

You can also have two separate @KafkaListener, each for every topic.
What works best for your use-case.